# Pulling JSON data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

```
{
    "issues": [
      {
        "id": "PCG8363042",
        "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conctetur adipiscing elit. Ut ut gravida dolor. Phasellus vitae sem.",
        "detailTitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conctetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu consectetur erat.",
        "reporter": "Sijo M Peter",
        "assignee": "Sijo M Peter",
        "assignee_desig": "UI/UX Designer",
        "type": "Task",
        "priority": "High",
        "status": "New",
        "resolution": "Unresplned",
        "fix_versions": "None",
        "affects": "None",
        "components": "None",
        "labels": "Webetc",
        "sprint": "C",
        "story_points": 6,
        "created": "01/02/2019",
        "updated": "01/02/2019",
        "votes": 0,
        "watchers": 1
      },
```

I am actually creating 9 cards using flex in css.I have used static data but now I have to use dynamic data from JSON file.As I am newbie in typescript,I want your help to render json file in flex container.I have given snippet of JSON file for 1 card above.The card for flex container is given below:

```
<div class="flex-container" >
  <div>
    <h3>ID:PCG30456</h3><span style="float:right;">January 02,2019</span>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsur dolor sit</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus malesuada diam faucibus. </p>
    <span>Assignee</span><span>Status</span>
    <img src="user_1.svg"><span>Sijo M Peter</span>
    <button>High Priority</button>
  </div>
```

I want to pull JSON code for such 9 cards.I have just started javascript and this has made my progress stop. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Make sure that you have `"resolveJsonModule": true` in the `"compilerOptions"` section of your  `tsconfig.json` file in order to read the `.json` file.  You will get all of the types inferred properly.  Are you looking for pure typescript?  Not React, Angular, etc?  Creating HTML code is really annoying without a helper.  You have to create each element with `document.createElement` and set its properties.  That part is just JS and does not change with TS.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ya I got that.But can you help me with JS code ..even that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Reading the JSON

In order to be able to parse the .json file, you need to make sure that you have `"resolveJsonModule": true` in the `"compilerOptions"` section of your tsconfig.json. That allows you to import the JSON object.

```
import json from "./data.json";
```

The imported object will have all of the types inferred properly. You can actually use the object to derive type declarations.

```
const issues = json.issues;

type Issue = typeof issues[number];
```

#### Executing a Script

We will define a function that inserts cards into the DOM (the DOM is an object representation of the HTML code).  We need to somehow *call* that function.  There are a lot of ways to do this.  You can use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to keep your variables out of the global scope.  You can add your function as an event listener to the DOMContentLoaded event, etc.

I am just calling the function at the top-level of the file because I'm not going through any build step here.  The function will run when `"main.ts"` is loaded.  I am loading it through a `script` tag in the HTML.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="card-container" class="flex-container" />
<script type="module" src="./main.ts"></script>
```

#### Creating HTML with Javascript

Creating and adding elements to the DOM in pure Javascript/Typescript is really verbose and annoying.  A lot of people use libraries like React, Angular, etc. to make it easier.

You have to create each element with `document.createElement`, set its properties, and append it to the DOM by calling `parent.appendChild` on its desired parent.

You could do this all in one function, but I like to break up code into pieces.  We have one function `createCard` that takes an `Issue` and returns an `HTMLDivElement`.  Then we have a function `insertIssues` that loops through the array from the JSON and inserts a card for each issue.

main.ts

```
import json from "./data.json";

const issues = json.issues;

// derive type declaration based on the json variable
type Issue = typeof issues[number];

// helper function creates a card element for one issue
// return type is inferred as HTMLDivElement
const createCard = (issue: Issue) => {
    // create card div
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    // create h3 with id
    const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.innerText = `ID:${issue.id}`;
    div.appendChild(h3);
    // create span with date
    const date = document.createElement("span");
    date.style.float = "right"; // can set style properties
    date.innerText = new Date(issue.created).toDateString();
    // create h2 with title
    const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    h2.innerText = issue.title;
    div.appendChild(h2);

    // TODO: add other fields

    // return the composed card div element
    return div;
};

const insertIssues = () => {
    const target = document.getElementById(
        "card-container",
    );
    // in case no target was found
    if (!target) {
        console.log("no target container");
        return;
    }
    // create an element for each issue
    const cards = issues.map(createCard);
    // append each card to the target element
    // need to use an arrow function, cannot do cards.forEach(target.appendChild);
    cards.forEach((card) => target.appendChild(card));
};

// invoke the function
insertIssues();
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-from-json-in-vanilla-ts-05hju?file=/main.ts)